# EFI entry disappears after reboot

Tags: boot, uefi, raid

I have a Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS on a raid 1.
At the moment it is **booting only from the second SSD (`sdb`)**.
I like to clone the boot entry to `sda` to have redundancy in case of a failure.
It is on a Supermicro X11SCM-F mainboard.

The problem is that the **second EFI entry disappears after each reboot**.
I created the entry automatically with

```
grub-install --bootloader-id ubuntu2 /dev/sda
```

and also manually with

```
efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sdb -p 1 -L "ubuntu2" -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\shimx64.efi
```

When I check it with `efibootmgr -v` both entries appear:

`efibootmgr -v`

```
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,0003,0001
Boot0000* ubuntu2       HD(1,GPT,94737db1-cd19-4781-81ae-f37c9f006ba6,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001  Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,0200)..GO..NO..........S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .8.8.3. .D.C.T. .9.6.0.G.B...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X.........A..........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.4.S.6.8.X.N.M.0.0.5.1.1.9.1. .X. . . . .......BO..NO..........S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .8.8.3. .D.C.T. .9.6.0.G.B...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X.........A..........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.4.S.6.8.X.N.M.0.0.5.1.1.4.2. .K. . . . .......BO
Boot0003  UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell      VenMedia(5023b95c-db26-429b-a648-bd47664c8012)..BO
Boot0004* ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,de848ea8-007f-42ad-9fc5-8c01379bce86,0x800,0xf3800)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO
```

But after a reboot only the entry from `sdb` is left:

```
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0003,0001
Boot0001  Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)/VenHw(5ce8128b-2cec-40f0-8372-80640e3dc858,                                                                       0200)..GO..NO..........S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.D. .8.8.3. .D.C.T. .9.6.0.G.B........                                                                       ...........\.,.@.r.d.=.X.........A..........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.4.                                                                       S.6.8.X.N.M.0.0.5.1.1.9.1. .X. . . . .......BO..NO..........S.a.m.s.u.n.g. .S.S.                                                                       D. .8.8.3. .D.C.T. .9.6.0.G.B...................\.,.@.r.d.=.X.........A.........                                                                       .................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.4.S.6.8.X.N.M.0.0.5.1.1.4.2. .K. . . . ......                                                                       .BO
Boot0003  UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell      VenMedia(5023b95c-db26-429b-a648-bd47664                                                                       c8012)..BO
Boot0004* ubuntu        HD(1,GPT,de848ea8-007f-42ad-9fc5-8c01379bce86,0x800,0xf3                                                                       800)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)..BO
```

The partition table is the same:
`parted /dev/sda print`

```
Modell: ATA Samsung SSD 883 (scsi)
Festplatte  /dev/sda:  960GB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/4096B
Partitionstabelle: gpt
Disk-Flags: pmbr_boot

Nummer  Anfang  Ende    Größe   Dateisystem     Name    Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   fat32           EFI     boot, esp
 2      512MB   32.5GB  32.0GB  linux-swap(v1)  Swap
 3      32.5GB  113GB   80.0GB                  root1   RAID
 4      113GB   513GB   400GB                   daten1  RAID
```

`parted /dev/sdb print`

```
Modell: ATA Samsung SSD 883 (scsi)
Festplatte  /dev/sdb:  960GB
Sektorgröße (logisch/physisch): 512B/4096B
Partitionstabelle: gpt
Disk-Flags:

Nummer  Anfang  Ende    Größe   Dateisystem     Name    Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   fat32           EFI     boot, esp
 2      512MB   32.5GB  32.0GB  linux-swap(v1)  Swap
 3      32.5GB  113GB   80.0GB                  root2   RAID
 4      113GB   513GB   400GB                   daten2  RAID
```

And also the partition data is the same:
`gdisk /dev/sda`

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): i
Partition number (1-4): 1
Partition GUID code: C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B (EFI System)
Partition unique GUID: 94737DB1-CD19-4781-81AE-F37C9F006BA6
First sector: 2048 (at 1024.0 KiB)
Last sector: 999423 (at 488.0 MiB)
Partition size: 997376 sectors (487.0 MiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'EFI'
```

`gdisk /dev/sdb`

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): i
Partition number (1-4): 1
Partition GUID code: C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B (EFI System)
Partition unique GUID: DE848EA8-007F-42AD-9FC5-8C01379BCE86
First sector: 2048 (at 1024.0 KiB)
Last sector: 999423 (at 488.0 MiB)
Partition size: 997376 sectors (487.0 MiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'EFI'
```

Maybe there is a problem about the mainboard firmware? I updated the UEFI-Bios to the latest version but it doesn't help.

Do you have ideas on how to solve this?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: UEFI typically removes UEFI entries if drive is disconnected. Is drive not seen on reboot? UEFI uses the unique GUID/partUUID to identify ESP. You also can see GUID/partUUID with. `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"`

Comment: Note that the `/boot/efi/EFI` (or where is yours) entry is still there, use `efibootmgr` to set it back.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer.
I could solve it: the problem was the disk-flag **pmbr_boot** on /dev/sda.
The command `parted -s /dev/sda disk_set pmbr_boot off` removed it and now the UEFI recognise the ssd as boot device.
More [infos about the pmbr_boot flag here](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019468).

Comment: That was it. `gparted` can do that in a GUI, more user friendly.